# Recreating activity with getting a notification

Tags: java, android

There is the following task:

There is the first activity (for example, "Activity A"), and the second activity ("Activity B"). Also there is some Service (just "Service) for catching notifications from my server. I'd like to realize the following algorithm:

1. User is on "Activity A" or "Activity B"
2. "Service" catches some notification from my server
3. If user is on "Activity A" then service should create notification on Notification Bar; if user is on "Activity B" already the service should just recreate "Activity B" without creating a notification.
4. If notification has been created user could click by it and go to "Activity B"

I've made all steps without the third one, because I don't know how I can get the current activity. Please, tell me, is there any way to detect which activity is current? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "legit" way of getting the `Activity` the user is on.

You can always do a hack :

- declare a `static boolean sVisible` member in your `ActivityB` class
- in `onStart()`, set that flag to `true`
- in `onStop()`, set that flag to `false`
- in your `Service` check  `if(ActivityB.sVisible)`